# Why do I get HTTP 500 errors trying to serve PHP content out of an IIS 6 virtual directory?

Tags: php, iis-6, 500-error, virtualdirectories

I know PHP is working, because when I browse directly to a file in wwwroot, it's served fine.  And the virtual directory is working, because when I browse to html files in the virtual directory, they're served.  But when I browse to a PHP file in the virtual directory, I receive an HTTP 500 error from IIS.

Searching on the web, I found a bunch of suggestions to confirm that doc_root in php.ini is blank - however, it is and it's still not working.

Other configuration settings going on: Integrated Windows authentication is turned on, client certificates are required, and client certificate mapping is enabled.  All of it is working fine for PHP content not in a virtual directory.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

See what you can to do find out which 500 error you're getting.  Make sure that you have IE friendly errors turned off (if you're using IE), and if you still don't get a good error, check the IIS logs to get the 500 sub-status code.  That will likely give a big clue as to the exact error and what to do about it.